# Calling each key and value in json in groovy pipeline

Tags: json, bash, jenkins, groovy, devops

I have a task to be able to read a json file from a gitlab and then called the json file based on each envioronment selected in the parameter. For example now, I have Upgrade and BV, and Upgrade is selected, it should be able to read based on this key value pairing below:

Expected value to get from the json

```
  $.[env].level 
$.[env].domain 
$.[env].resources 
$.[env].resources.db-schemas 
$.[env].resources.db-schemas.[name].
$.[env].resources.db-schemas.[name].
$.[env].resources.db-schemas.[name].
$.[env].resources.db-schemas.[name].jvm 
$.[env].jvm 
$.[env].jvm.[type] 
$.[env].jvm.[type](.jvm-name) 
$.[env].jvm.[type](.jvm-name).jenkins-name 
$.[env].jvm.[type](.jvm-name).host 
$.[env].jvm.[type](.jvm-name).ip 
$.[env].jvm.[type](.jvm-name.port)
```

The $.[env] is the params that might be selected either upgrade or BV.

The json file contains :

```
   {
    "upgrade": {
        "level": 1,
        "domain": "develop.autosample.co.uk",
        "resources": {
            "db-schemas": {
                "rule": {
                    "schema": "pegarules",
                    "database": "sas_develop",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                },
                "data": {
                    "schema": "pegadata",
                    "database": "sas_develop",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                },
                "report": {
                    "schema": "pegareports",
                    "database": "sas_develop",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                }
            }
        },
        "jvm": {
            "load-balancer": null,
            "pega": [{
                "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasw02",
                "host": "ent-giem-sasw02",
                "ip": "x.x.x.x"
            }],
            "db": {
                "primary": {
                    "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasrd26",
                    "host": "ent-giem-sasrd26",
                    "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                    "port": 5432
                },
                "secondary": {
                    "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasrd98",
                    "host": "ent-giem-pgrd98",
                    "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                    "port": 5432
                }
            }

        }
    },

    "BV": {
        "level": 1,
        "domain": "BV.autosample.co.uk",
        "resources": {
            "db-schemas": {
                "rule": {
                    "schema": "pegarules",
                    "database": "sas_bv",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                },
                "data": {
                    "schema": "pegadata",
                    "database": "sas_bv",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                },
                "report": {
                    "schema": "pegareports",
                    "database": "sas_bv",
                    "jvm": ["primary", "secondary"]
                }
            }
        },
        "jvm": {
            "load-balancer": null,
            "pega": [{
                "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasw02",
                "host": "bv-giem-sasw02",
                "ip": "x.x.x.x"
            }],
            "db": {
                "primary": {
                    "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasrd26",
                    "host": "bv-giem-sasrd26",
                    "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                    "port": 5432
                },
                "secondary": {
                    "jenkins-name": "ent-giem-sasrd98",
                    "host": "bv-giem-pgrd98",
                    "ip": "x.x.x.x",
                    "port": 5432
                }
            }
        }



    }

}
```

The groovy code at the moment which even though is reading the json, I need to know how to call based on the key and value indicated above :

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy    

node{
    properties([
    parameters([

   choice(
        name: 'environment',
        choices: ['','Upgrade','BV' ],
        description: 'environment to choose'
        ),

    ])
]) 

    deleteDir()
        dir('dir-switch') {

    stage('Checkout') {
   
   // git branch: 'test-upgrade-json', url: 'https://gitlab.xxxxxxx/pipeline.git'
  // stash includes: '**', name: 'upgrade-pega'
        
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/test-upgrade-json']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-github', url: 'https://gitlab.xxxxx/pipeline.git']]])
                
    }

     
            stage('Get Environment') {
            sh """
                ls -lart ./*
                ls ${env.WORKSPACE}
                cp -R ./upgrade-pega/environment/env.json  /${env.WORKSPACE}/dir-switch
                ls /${env.WORKSPACE}/dir-switch
            """
        
          }  


def obj = readJSON file: './env.json'
def list = obj[params.environment];

println list

list.each { println it }


 


stage('JVM check content') { 

/////   print each key and value in the json to be able to used in the code pipeline

         
     
sh """
  echo -e "-------------------------------System Information of current node running ----------------------------"
  echo -e "Hostname:\t\t"`hostname`
  echo -e "System Main IP:\t\t"`hostname -I`

""".stripIndent()

/// the text file now in the workspace in the folder dir-switch





                }
   




        }



}
```

The error am seeing is :

```
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1488 of {
 "upgrade": {
        "level": 1,
        "domain": "develop.autosample.co.uk",
        "resources": {
            "db-schemas":
'''''
'''''     
.....

            "port": 5432
                }
            }
        }
    }
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:1043)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:139)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Groovy issue.  Your JSON has a syntax error in it.  There is a missing } to close off "upgrade" object.  So this is what you posted:

```
{
    "upgrade": {
     ...
    "BV": {
     ...
}
```

What it should be is:

```
{
    "upgrade": {
    ...
    },
    "BV": {
    ...
    }
}
```

It appears both `upgrade` and `BV` are missing the closing `}` in the JSON, and you need a comma (`,`) between properties of the root object (i.e "upgrade" and "BV").

You also have differences is capitalization with what you delcared in your JSON and what you have in your:

```
choice(
    name: 'environment',
    choices: ['','Upgrade','BV' ],  <<<<<<<<< Upgrade vs upgrade!
    description: 'environment to choose'
    ),

])
```

and in your JSON:

```
{
  "upgrade": {    <<<< probably should make them match
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have edited the json to be validated. But the issue am having is still not picking up values. It is getting null. the new error is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method last() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)

Comment: Check my updated answer.  At this point it seems to be an exercise in debugging what you've written and being thorough.  It definitely feels like these suggestions are making an impact on your work and they would be worthy of an upvote and an awarded answer.

Comment: yes agreed have updated the vote

Comment: It is successful  with this when I select upgrade for example,   but how would I call into jenkins based on individual key and value rather than all outputs under Upgrade :  The out currently is {"level":1,"domain":"develop.autosample.co.uk","resources":{"db-schemas":{"rule":{"schema":"pegarules","database":"sas_develop","jvm":["primary","secondary"]},"data":{"schema":"pegadata","database":"sas_develop","jvm":["primary","secondary"]},"report":{"schema":"pegareports","database":"sas_develop","jvm":["primary","secondary"]}}},"jvm":{"load
--------
-----

Comment: This is another question.  It's too hard to follow what you're asking with such little space as a comment.

Comment: will accept the answer and ask in another question